# getting global name not defined error

Tags: python, growlnotify

i have the following class

```
class notify():
    def __init__(self,server="localhost", port=23053):
        self.host = server
        self.port = port
        register = gntp.GNTPRegister()
        register.add_header('Application-Name',"SVN Monitor")
        register.add_notification("svnupdate",True)
        growl(register)    

    def svn_update(self, author="Unknown", files=0):  
        notice = gntp.GNTPNotice()
        notice.add_header('Application-Name',"SVN Monitor")
        notice.add_header('Notification-Name', "svnupdate")
        notice.add_header('Notification-Title',"SVN Commit")
        # notice.add_header('Notification-Icon',"")
        notice.add_header('Notification-Text',Msg)
        growl(notice)

    def growl(data):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((self.host,self.port))
        s.send(data)
        response = gntp.parse_gntp(s.recv(1024))
        print response
        s.close()
```

but when ever i try to use this class via  the follwoing code i get `NameError: global name 'growl' is not defined`

```
from growlnotify import *
n  = notify()
n.svn_update()
```

any one has an idea what is going on here ?

cheers 
nash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance scope is not searched as part of scope resolution in Python. If you want to call a method on `self` then you must prefix it with a reference to `self`.

```
self.growl(register)
```

Answer (score 1):

`growl` is not a global symbol, it's a member of the `notify` class.

Inside the `notify` class, call the `growl` method as follows:

```
self.growl(notice)
```